# Is there a way of checking for membership from the values of a dictionary? Once confirmed, can we do other things?

Tags: python, dictionary

I understand that it's quite easy to check if a key is available in a dictionary, but what about certain values?

So, what I have here is a dictionary of lists where the key references a set of, for consistency's sake, strings. It would look a bit like this:

```
menu = {'breakfast':['soft-boiled eggs', 'hash brown', 'Earl Grey'], 
        'lunch':['pasta', 'soup'], 
        'dinner':['chips', 'beef stew', 'veggies']}
```

Now what I'd like to do is check if, say, `'chips'` is in my menu and if so, I'd like to replace it with `'crusty bread'`. I know I can try using `'chips' in menu['lunch']` or the same for breakfast, but what if I don't know when it's being served?

`Extension`

While this is harder to explain let's say we've a class called Food defined such:

```
class Food(object):
def __init__(self, meal):
    self.meal = meal
    self.ingredients = collections.defaultdict(set)
def __str__(self):
    return "%s" %(self.meal)
```

Here, `meal` will refer to either breakfast, lunch or dinner. And we have `ingredients` which is a dictionary of sets. `'potatoes'` is an ingredient and when keyed we'll have the relevant dishes show up: hash browns, chips. As such, when I call `print meal, menu[meal].ingredients` for my function, I get the following result (this is only for breakfast since that's all I've put in):

```
breakfast defaultdict(<type 'set'>, {'potatoes': set(['chips', 'hash brown']), 'eggs': set(['omelette', 'hard-boiled', 'soft-boiled']), 'tea': set(['Assam', 'Earl Grey', 'English'])})
```

So this is basically what's available for breakfast for specific 'ingredients'.

Now, let's assume the worst has happened and I've run out of potatoes! What I'd like to do now is replace `'potatoes'` with `'bread'` under which I'll have the values/types `'roll', 'crusty', 'brown'`. How would one go about doing that?

And to top things off, towards lunch-time, we run out of `'Assam'` tea. Similar to the question before the Extension, how would I remove that (after checking to see if it existed in the first place)?

Comment: Your breakfast example is curious: potatoes are used in chips etc, eggs are used in omelettes etc, and tea is used in Assam, Earl Grey etc. So the customers get the same tea leaves irrespective of what kind of tea they order? This exercise appears to be homework from the Basil Fawlty College of Hospitality :-)

Comment: And your model needs a bit of normalisation: tea can be ordered at any meal and many dishes can be ordered at both lunch and dinner; you really don't want to specify the ingredients of Chicken Parmigiana or  Vindaloo more than once. How are you going to store all of this data on disk? pickle? Have you considered a relational database?

Comment: @KennyTM: This isn't my actual problem. But in the process of trying to solve the real one, I decided to focus on that bit of the problem - and came up with this out of the blue. Because I was hungry. So yeah, it's fun - but with purpose.

Comment: @John Machin: I've only just begun getting used to Python, so would you be so kind as to elaborate a bit?

Comment: @John Machin: The previous comment was regarding `pickle`, sorry. And to answer your first comment - I suppose so! It's more like potatoes are used _for_ chips, eggs are used _for_ omelettes. I suppose the word 'ingredient' was wrong but I was making this on the fly. I think in my mind it worked like this: what teas do we offer? Assam, Earl Grey, English. How would you like your eggs done? So on and so forth. It's a very quick and dirty representation of something that could be a very interesting exercise in the future.

Comment: @Az: pickle: See http://docs.python.org/library/pickle.html ... what I was trying to point you at was a database

Comment: @Az: tea: "Assam tea leaves" (and "boiling water") are (ingredients of|used in|used for) the menu item "Assam tea" ... same relation however expressed. Manner of cooking the menu item (eggs soft|hard, steak rare|medium|well done) is a different relation, not to be muddled in with the ingredients. You also need a relation to record which menu items are available at breakfast|lunch|etc. Run out of Assam tea leaves, don't delete (aarrgghh!!), mark it as unavailable and order more. A proper data model in any language with all the dicts and lists to handle queries is too complex; use a database.

Comment: @John Machin: Despite using this as an example, it seems that I've stumbled upon something that's a challenge in its own right. In fact the original problem I'm dealing with is probably far less complicated. While using a database is relatively outside the scope of that - I would be very interested in finding out how a relational database model works. Any suggestions? I can always Google, but I highly value the advice from someone knowledgeable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Membership in `menu` is easy:

```
[k for k, v in menu.iteritems() if 'chips' in v]
```

Membership with `defaultdict` works exactly the same way since containment checking doesn't mutate it.

Comment: Is that a list comprehension you've used, by any chance?

Comment: It is. Since there are multiple possible answers, we need some sort of a structure that will return them all.

Answer (score 0):

One obvious way is to just go thru whole dict and replace the values but IMO it is better to design it so that it is easy to replace ingredients e.g. have a single object(may be singleton class) for each type of ingredient, so you can just replace the types on the fly e.g.

```
tea.remove('assam')
```

and it will affect all the places where tea was being referred. similarly you can keep track of the meals where tea was being used, in some kind of registry and update registry if you want to remove tea from all the meals or may be flag tea as deleted, or want to replace potato with bread, do that in registry, which in turn can ask each meal to do that

```
registry.replace(potato, bread)
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the basic thing you're asking for is how to iterate through a dictionary -- once you have that, it's all basic stuff.

```
for key,value in mydict.iteritems():
    print "%s = %s" %(key, value)
```

now, to apply it directly to your situation:

```
for meal, food in menu.iteritems():
    if 'potatoes' in food.ingredients:
        del food.ingredients['potatoes']
        food.ingredients['bread'] = set(['roll', 'crusty', 'brown'])
```

'del' can be used to remove a key/value pair from a dictionary